# Why does this problem happen in python function scope?

Tags: python, function, scope

If I run this script:

```
def main_function():
    b = 'b'

    def nested_function():
        print(b)
        #b = 'value change'

    nested_function()

main_function()
```

All is ok.

If I run this another script:

```
def main_function():
    b = 'b'

    def nested_function():
        #print(b)
        b = 'value change'

    nested_function()

main_function()
```

All is ok too. As you can see, here I change the line inside in the nested_function().

But if I use the two lines
`print(b)` and `b='value change'` in the nested_function(). Like this:

```
def main_function():
    b = 'b'

    def nested_function():
        print(b)
        b = 'value change'

    nested_function()

main_function()
```

Then, there is an error.
The error says:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment

I can't understand the logic of why this happens.

Comment: If a function contains an assignment to a variable, that variable is local by default (unless overridden by a `global` or `nonlocal` declaration).  That is the entirety of Python's rules on variable scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break these down one-by-one. Python's scoping rules are a bit unhinged sometimes. The basic idea is that if you *ever* assign to a variable inside of a given function, then Python assumes that that variable is local to that particular function.

```
def main_function():
    b = 'b'

    def nested_function():
        print(b)

    nested_function()

main_function()
```

Here, you never assign to `b` inside of `nested_function`, so Python sees no need to create a new variable. Instead, it inherits the one from its enclosing scope.

```
def main_function():
    b = 'b'

    def nested_function():
        b = 'value change'

    nested_function()

main_function()
```

Here, you *do* assign to it, so you get a new variable. The `b` you assign to inside of `nested_function` is *unrelated* to the one inside of `main_function`. They just happen to share a name.

```
def main_function():
    b = 'b'

    def nested_function():
        print(b)
        b = 'value change'

    nested_function()

main_function()
```

Here, you *do* assign, so Python makes a new variable inside of the function, and *every* reference to `b` inside the nested function refers to that new variable, so it's as if you did this.

```
def main_function():
    b_0 = 'b'

    def nested_function():
        print(b_1)
        b_1 = 'value change'

    nested_function()

main_function()
```

So you're trying to print out `b_1` before any value has been assigned to it, hence the error.

If `b` was a module-level variable, you would use the `global` keyword to mark it as such inside the function. In your case, it's a local variable; it's just not local to the immediately enclosing function. So we use the `nonlocal` keyword.

```
def main_function():
    b = 'b'

    def nested_function():
        nonlocal b
        print(b)
        b = 'value change'

    nested_function()

main_function()
```

`nonlocal b` says "I know I'm assigning to `b`, but I actually mean to use the one from the enclosing scope".